# Can't Mock Anything in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I'm new to Unit testing and Tried to Mock a map using Mockito.

When I tried to mock ConcurrentHashMap it  throws error like this . Not only Hash map it throws error for all Object .

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

class UtilsTest {


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        ConcurrentHashMap mockedMap = mock(ConcurrentHashMap.class);
    }

    @Test
    void lessLoadedServersCount(){

    }
}
```

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.

Mockito can only non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : OpenLogic
JVM vendor version : 11.0.19+7-adhoc.admin.jdk11u
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.19+7-adhoc.admin.jdk11u
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 13.2.1



Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Tried With List and Sets as well getting same error . I tried with JDK 19 getting same error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.ArrayList.

Mockito can only non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.HashSet.

Mockito can only non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

Comment: Why in the world would you want to mock a collection?

Comment: And if you did want to mock a collection, it would generally make more sense to mock the interface, not a specific implementation, since most code shouldn't care about the specific implementation class of a collection. e.g. `mock(Map.class)`, `mock(Set.class)`, or `mock(List.class)`; not `mock(ConcurrentHashMap.class)`, `mock(HashSet.class)` or `mock(ArrayList.class)`.

Comment: Have you tried mocking an interface, or mocking a class that isn't final?  For instance, `public class MyClass { public String pleaseMockMe() { return "Not yet mocked"; } }` `mock(MyClass.class)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Mockito do you use?

I create an example in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-mockito-concurrent-hashmap) and mocking `ConcurrentHashMap` seems to work fine.

```
class UtilTest {

    private ConcurrentHashMap map;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        map = mock(ConcurrentHashMap.class);
    }

    @Test
    void test(){
        when(map.get("key")).thenReturn("value");

        assertEquals("value", map.get("key"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my build file already contained an old version of mockito, which I didn't notice earlier. So, I added the new mockito dependency, which resolved this error.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad the issue is resolved.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39), Mockito versions between 2.1.0 (inclusive) and 5.0.0 (exclusive) allowed mocking final classes, but it was disabled by default.  Starting with 5.0.0, it was enabled by default.  Which would explain why it didn't work until the version was upgraded.